# Adding a new operator symbol to a custom language in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I'd like to create a custom operator for a custom language I'm highlighting in Notepad++.  Has anyone done this in the past?  A special character that often comes up in my language is the yen symbol (`￥`), and I would like to highlight the phrases immediately following and immediately preceding that symbol; unfortunately, I cannot figure a way to add a custom operator, of it is even possible.

Also, if anyone has any additional tag recommendations, please edit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible through the GUI, but you might be able to do it by manually adding it to the language XML file.

Have a look at the %APPDATA%\Notepad++\UserDefinedLang.xml and try adding it there.

Not sure if it'll work though, as I've no idea if the parser they're using has support for non-standard characters..